# Search excel using list separated by commas and return multiple values separated by commas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to build an Excel Formula that uses a abbreviation(s) defined in a cell to find a description on a different sheet. These abbreviation(s) are separated by commas, in the case of multiple instances. They are selected using a drop down list.

Using a single abbreviation I have been able to realize, but I am not able to separate multiple abbreviations and search for each one of them.

Is this at all possible without using VBA?

If so how would I search using the split abbreviations and return their respective values?

**Example excel**

*Current Input | Output*

[image]

*Desired Input | Output*

[image]

**Search matrix**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, you are not searching.. you are 'decoding'. For example, from [ a,b,g  ] you want to make it [ alpha, beta, gamma ]. For that, you just use recursive substitute function.

Assuming [ a,b,g  ] is located in A1, put this in B1 and see the results:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"a","alpha"),"b","beta"),"g","gamma")
```

You may try to change A1 to [ a,g ] and see the effect. ( :

Once you get it, you may just replace it with all the values in you 'decoding' table. You can also link to the text using the cell address and 'locking' its row n column using $ . Or even better, use your range (reference : https://exceljet.net/formula/find-and-replace-multiple-values ).

Please share if it works/not/understandable.

Comment: You have hardcoded your translation table into the formula. I understand that the OP wants to perform the substitution based on data in the sheet.

Comment: That's why I propose to link to the values(text) instead of writing it. (I get the concern, but I'm stuck at how to 'handle' the comma in the input cell. Plus, the OP didn't mention the maximum elements per input cell. With that info, a recursive index match solution is possible.)

Comment: I tried a couple of formula's, when using the list that are defined on the second sheet i don't see how a second substitute functions should be used. The formula that got some result was the following:

= SUBSTITUEREN(G4; Blad2!I$1:I$100; Blad2!J$1:J$100)

However for some reason this only returns the description of the second abbreviation in the list. I will post a snip in a different answer

Comment: try `= SUBSTITUEREN( SUBSTITUEREN( SUBSTITUEREN(  SUBSTITUEREN(G4; Blad2!I$1:I$100; Blad2!J$1:J$100) ; Blad2!I$1:I$100; Blad2!J$1:J$100) ; Blad2!I$1:I$100; Blad2!J$1:J$100) ; Blad2!I$1:I$100; Blad2!J$1:J$100)`

Comment: Btw, how much is the maximum number of elements per input cell in G4 ?

Comment: The maximmum number of elements that could be in the cell is virtually endless. Ofcourse not really but every element of the list could be included and the list might not yet be complete

Comment: Same behavior as SUBSTITUTE(G4; Blad2!I$1:I$100; Blad2!J$1:J$100)

Comment: Oh.. i see.. what I meant by " the maximum number of elements per input cell in G4 " is.. | the [ yO, yD , TH ] is 3 elements, and [ yO, RUN ] is 2 elements. what is the number of elements you anticipate ?

Comment: I can't anticipate any value, this might increase when objects are added.
I did find a weird correlation with the description being shown. When i move the list it seems to only be able to retrive the description that is in the fourth row.

Comment: I can now confirm that the only description being fetch is the one that is positioned on the same row as the cell where they should be shown

Comment: can we meet [here](http://www.disposablechat.com/chat/jump?password=) ?

Comment: Yes! How do i log on?

Answer (score 0):

The result of the following formula:
= SUBSTITUTE(G4; Blad2!I$1:I$100; Blad2!J$1:J$100)

However this only seems to work for one abbreviation and only on the first row where it is applied...

[image]